# Rendering a matrix (or grid) using thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, matrix, thymeleaf

I have an legacy structure I need to use to render a matrix (or grid) using thymeleaf in a Springboot project.

I have several models to represent it with additional info.

```
public class CeldaGrid {
    private int valor;
   //Removed additional fields
   //Constructor
   //Getters/Setter


public class MiGrid {
    //Represent each column of the matrix
    private Collection<CeldaGrid> celdaGridList;
    //Constructor
    //Getter/Setter


public class ContenedorGrid {
    //Represent the matrix
    private Collection<MiGrid> gridList = new ArrayList<MiGrid>();
    //Constructor
    //Getter/Setter
```

This is how I initialze, in this case is 3x3 matrix (it could be different size):

```
Collection<MiGrid> gridList = new ArrayList<MiGrid>();

// Row 1
MiGrid miGrid = new MiGrid();
Collection<CeldaGrid> celdaGridList = new ArrayList<CeldaGrid>();

CeldaGrid celdaGrid = new CeldaGrid();
celdaGrid.setValor(1);
celdaGridList.add(celdaGrid);

celdaGrid = new CeldaGrid();
celdaGrid.setValor(2);
celdaGridList.add(celdaGrid);

celdaGrid = new CeldaGrid();
celdaGrid.setValor(3);
celdaGridList.add(celdaGrid);

miGrid.setCeldaGridList(celdaGridList);
gridList.add(miGrid);

// Row 2
miGrid = new MiGrid();
celdaGridList = new ArrayList<CeldaGrid>();
celdaGrid = new CeldaGrid();

celdaGrid.setValor(4);
celdaGridList.add(celdaGrid);

celdaGrid = new CeldaGrid();
celdaGrid.setValor(5);
celdaGridList.add(celdaGrid);

celdaGrid = new CeldaGrid();
celdaGrid.setValor(6);
celdaGridList.add(celdaGrid);


miGrid.setCeldaGridList(celdaGridList);
gridList.add(miGrid);

ContenedorGrid contenedorGrid = new ContenedorGrid();
contenedorGrid.setGridList(gridList);
model.addAttribute("contenedorgrid", contenedorGrid);
```

and finally the page:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/}" th:object="${contenedorgrid}" method="post">
  <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="eachCelda,indexList : *{gridList}">
      <td th:each="celda,indexCelda: ${eachCelda.celdaGridList}">
        <input type="text" th:id="${celda.valor}"
               th:field="*{celdaGridList[__${indexCelda.index}__].valor}"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

This is the list with values:

```
[MiGrid [celdaGridList=[CeldaGrid [valor=1], CeldaGrid [valor=2], CeldaGrid [valor=3]]], MiGrid [celdaGridList=[CeldaGrid [valor=4], CeldaGrid [valor=5], CeldaGrid [valor=6]]]]
```

And this is the error:

> org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'celdaGridList[0]' of bean class
>   [org.cabildo.gestatur.model.grid.ContenedorGrid]: Bean property
>   'celdaGridList[0]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method:
>   Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the
>   setter?

Code:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ppyf3f0l6p3v2ig/AABjXsS_6Mu2nmKd-XBRTclua?dl=0

**UPDATE 1:**

Changed code from Collection to List, exactly the same error.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You should change type of field `celdaGridList` to `List<CeldaGrid>` inside **MiGrid** class.</strike>

`Collection` isn't ordered and it has no method `get(int index)` so value from specific index can not be fetched. But you are trying to do so with the line `th:field="*{celdaGridList[__${indexCelda.index}__].valor}`
, what results in exception.

**Update**

I've looked closer at your page.

You've declared an object `th:object="${contenedorgrid}"` which is of type **ContenedorGrid**. Then you've used an asterix selector `th:field="*{celdaGridList[__${indexCelda.index}__].valor}"` on this object what is equivalent to `th:field="${contenedorgrid.celdaGridList[__${indexCelda.index}__].valor}"` what is obviously wrong because it misses `gridList`.

Please update `th:field` attribute within your `<input>` with the following code:

```
th:field="*{gridList[__${indexList.index}__].celdaGridList[__${indexCelda.index}__].valor}"
```

Comment: Hi. Changed as you suggested (See code on dropbox). Same errors, it seems property celdaGridList not found, like if getter not working.....

Comment: @davisoski I believe I found the right solution. I've updated my aswer.